# Nextjs13 redirect to external url flashing issue

Tags: redirect, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am redirecting in page.tsx to external url after fetching data and if condition is met. But my website is shown for a split second before redirection. I want to avoid that flashing moment

```
export const dynamic = 'force-static'
export const revalidate = 300
....
const [someData] = await Promise.all(apiCalls)
  if (condition) {
    redirect('https://www.google.com', RedirectType.replace)
  }
  ...
    return (
    <Layout layoutProps={...} modalsProps={...}>
      <SectionsContainer sections={sections} />
    </Layout>
  )
```

Comment: Try adding return inside condition block. Anyway you're saying "after" and your using "await" so before finishing promise you'll see what you have set up to be seen which I don't know what that it could be.

Comment: This is a server component so from my understanding await doesn't make a difference